# Why am I running into errors?

Tags: python

I don't know why this is happening. I know it has something to do with calling 'A' because whenever 'A' is the middle value between 'C' and 'B', it cuts to else and prints "[-] Bug Detected."
My code:

```
import time, random
run = True
while run:
    a = random.randint(1, 10000)
    b = random.randint(1, 10000)
    c = random.randint(1, 10000)
    def min3(c, b , a):
        if a == b:
            print("A is equal to B.")
        elif a == c:
            print(" A is equal to C.")
        elif b == c:
            print("B is equal to C.")
        if a > c and b > c:
            print("C is the lowest value.")
        elif a < c and b < c:
            print("C is the highest value.")
        if b > a and b > c:
            print("B is the highest value.")
        elif b < a and b < c:
            print("B is the lowest value.")
        if a > b and a > c:
            print("A is the highest value.")
        elif a < b and a < c:
            print("A is the lowest value.")
        else:
            print("[-] Bug Detected.")
            time.sleep(1)
            print(c)
            time.sleep(1)
            print(b)
            time.sleep(1)
            print(a)
            time.sleep(1)
            print("Exiting.")
            exit()
    (min3(c, b, a))
    time.sleep(1)
    print("[+] No Bug Detected.")
    time.sleep(1)
    print(c)
    time.sleep(1)
    print(b)
    time.sleep(1)
    print(a)
    time.sleep(1)

exit()
```

Thank you if you can help and explain to me why this is.

Comment: What errors are you encountering? Please post the complete error message including traceback.

Comment: @kindall the error is just a string "[ - ] Bug Detected", which is shown in a print statement (see `else:`). Not a real error, just a test.

Comment: @kindall @PioKozi Right. No traceback or actual Python error, just my own code referring to `else:` because it did not know what to input.

Comment: OK, so what is your actual question? You don't know why it's printing that stuff? Because you told it to print that stuff when A is neither the largest nor the smallest value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your bug is because of the last `else`. Since it hangs off the last series of if/then, it will run unless one of those conditions is met. I.e. If "A" is the middle value, it is not `a > b and a > c` nor is it `a < b and a < c` ... the else runs. The `else` is only associated with the 4 lines above it, not the entire run of if/thens.

That said, I don't know if you're limited to using a series of if/thens ... but this code is a little cleaner, faster, and easier...

```
import time, random, sys
import collections

def min3(*args):
    # Add the values to a dictionary, so you can 
    # use the VALUES passed in to get the associated letter
    d = {a:"a", b:"b", c:"c"}
    # args is a list, so all three values are in it. 
    # So, just sort it lowest to highest
    sorted_x = sorted(args)
    # Then just print them out. 
    # Use the format command for ease
    print("The lowest  is '{}' (={})".format(d[sorted_x[0]], sorted_x[0]))
    print("The middle  is '{}' (={})".format(d[sorted_x[1]], sorted_x[1]))
    print("The highest is '{}' (={})".format(d[sorted_x[2]], sorted_x[2]))
    print("Exiting.")
    # exit() # Not needed

run = True
while run:
    a = random.randint(1, 10000)
    b = random.randint(1, 10000)
    c = random.randint(1, 10000)

    (min3(c, b, a))
    #time.sleep(1)
    print("[+] No Bug Detected.")
    #time.sleep(1)
    print(c)
    #time.sleep(1)
    print(b)
    #time.sleep(1)
    print(a)
    #time.sleep(1)
    run = False # remove for infinite run

# exit() # not needed
```

OUTPUT:

```
The lowest  is 'c' (=479)
The middle  is 'a' (=7758)
The highest is 'b' (=9618)
Exiting.
[+] No Bug Detected.
479
9618
7758
```

Comment: Great! Thank you. Just what I needed, although this code is quite complex (to me at least) for me because I just started a few days ago.

Comment: Ya. Its a little advanced. Search for the terms like `Python dictionary`, `Python list sorting` , `*args` (which means multiple variables passed in which becomes a list) and `**kwargs` (which mean variables passed in as a dictionary) to get some explanations. `d = {a:"a", b:"b", c:"c"` is a dictionary, where you can find the `values` (the letters "a", "b", or "c") by using the `keys` which are the real numbers that the variables a, b, and c held (7758, 9618, 479) when I made the dictionary.

Comment: Nice! The way you've used the sorted list like keys for the dictionary is really clever! Why didn't I *ever* think of that?

Comment: Thanks, although I just realized that will fail if two of the values are the same. So, that should be checked for in advance of creating the dict.

Answer (score 0):

You are printing "[ - ] Bug Detected" whenever a, b, c do not meet the criteria in the previous `if` statements.

`else` will only refer to as the first `if` statement (going backwards from it), so in your case `a > b and a > c` as well as `a < b and a < c`.

So in either case, a must be on either side of *both* b *and* c. A number in between the 2 is not accepted in your `if` statements.

Therefore, your program will print "[ - ] Bug Detected" if a is in between b and c. i.e. `b < a < c` or `c < a < b`.

Comment: I get what you are saying, but `So in either case, a must be on either side of both b and c.` Did you miss a word because I dont understand this sentence.

Comment: @TerraceMason I'm sure I didn't miss a word, it makes sense to me. "a", (after the comma) means the *number* we are calling a.

Comment: I get what you mean now, my bad.

Comment: Thanks for explaining, very appreciative since I'm new.

Answer (score 0):

```
def min3(c, b , a):
  maximum = max(a, b, c)

  if a == b:
    print("A is equal to B.")
  elif a == c:
    print(" A is equal to C.")
  elif b == c:
    print("B is equal to C.")

  if a == maximum:
    print("A is the highest value")
  elif b == maximum:
    print("B is the highest value")
  elif c == maximum:
    print("C is the highest value")
  else:
    print("[-] Bug Detected.")
```

Comment: I believe it's what the original code intended to do.

Comment: I don't see how that's relevant to the question. " *Thank you if you can help and explain to me why this is.* "